# JSON : Cannot read property 'value of a key' of undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, api, object

So, Im trying to deal with an API.
i successful load the json(which is an array of objects) in my browser like the following

```
0:
source: {id: null, name: "Protothema.uk"}
author: "james bond"
title: " A TITLE"
description: "A DESCRIPTION"
__proto__: Object
```

my code

```
$.getJSON("http://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=uk&category=health&apiKey=MYAPIKEY", function(data){
   //console.log(data);

   $.each(data,function(index,value){
       console.log(value);

    console.log(value[0]);       
     console.log(value[0].title)//Cannot read property 'title' of undefined
   });

});
```

when i try to print the whole index like `console.log(value[0]);` i successfully get all the objects of the index 0.

but when i try to print a specific value of key like `console.log(value[0].title)` i get **Cannot read property 'title' of undefined**

im stuck for hours, what im doing wrong?

Comment: The array only has 1 element, so there's no `value[1]`.

Comment: Try `value[0].title`

Comment: `value[0]`... not `value[1]`

Comment: @Barmar im sorry, i edit it. not ```value[1]``` i mean i still want to get  ```console.log(value[0].title)```

Comment: Now I'm guessing that you're trying to print it before the API call has returned. Remember that API calls are asynchronous, you should print the result in the callback function, not right after making the call.

Comment: @MosiaThabo i just edited bro, my fault

Comment: But unless you show your actual code, it's just a guess.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-undefined-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron

Comment: Thank you ,Im new to the 'api world'. So where i can find this callback function or anything that will be usefull

Comment: That's impossible then. If value[0] prints an object with title key and yet when you access the key all of a sudden value[0] is undefined?

Comment: @MosiaThabo The console has live objects, so the array can change before you expand it.

Comment: @Barmar Correct, that's possible. But I am confused by his wording. The thing is `data : Object[]` so that means every item on `data` is actually an `object`. So in his case, he's treating item as another array, which is kind of confusing taking into account his opening statement on the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Structure of Response `data`:
[image]

Based on the structure, try access title of every article:

```
// Using JQuery.each() 
$.each(data.articles,function(index, article){
  console.log(article.title); // to access title of each article.
});
```

Comment: im already using ```console.log(value)``` and prints all the object. However ```value.title``` gives : undefined

Comment: Please check my answer and try the using `Object.keys` to check the authenticity of that object before using it?

Comment: the ```0:``` is an index of the array that contains an object. this object has some elements, ok? one of them is ```title: " A TITLE"``` so value of the name title is a string

Comment: Can you please console data and show me it's structure? I agree with what you're saying but it's what you explained on the question. I think seeing the structure of data would help

Comment: Based on what you just said, then I'm not convinced that `data: Object[]`, data is not a list of object because data[0] == value, and if you're saying value also has an index:0, it means value is also an array

Comment: You can insert a picture of `console.log(data)` please on your question.

Comment: this is the result of the console.log(data) https://ibb.co/c14wGVn

Comment: Cool thanks, so data is equal that whole object which has property `articles of type Object[]`... so could you try `console.log(data.articles[0])` and `console.log(data.articles[0].title)`

Comment: my man you are awesome, thank you so much for your time and your patience. This world needs more people like you. Again thanks <3

Comment: Pleasure my man. I've wasted days before in codes like this and I was helped, someone did the same thing. Patient and never lost hope even though I was getting irritated by their multiple questions. So since then I knew that you must always be patient with people.